# Point in polygon written in scala

Tags: scala

I was wondering the best way to covert this C# method to Scala Function, it seems like this could be more concise using scala's sytax.

```
bool IsPointInPolygon(List<Loc> poly, Loc point)
{
    int i, j;
    bool c = false;
    for (i = 0, j = poly.Count - 1; i < poly.Count; j = i++)
    {
        if ((((poly[i].Lt <= point.Lt) && (point.Lt < poly[j].Lt)) ||
            ((poly[j].Lt <= point.Lt) && (point.Lt < poly[i].Lt))) &&
            (point.Lg < (poly[j].Lg - poly[i].Lg) * (point.Lt - poly[i].Lt) /
            (poly[j].Lt - poly[i].Lt) + poly[i].Lg))
                c = !c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken that your algorithm is correct, you can observe that the resulting `boolean` is obtained by toggling each time a certain condition is met. Therefore you could *count* those conditions.

Furthermore you are iterating through the points pairwise (`j` is basically `i - 1` if I understand the code correct, except for the initial iteration where `j` must be wrapped back to `poly.Count - 1`).

To get the pairs, if `poly` is a `scala.List`:

```
val pairs = (poly.last :: poly).sliding(2, 1)
```

That prepends the last element to the list before forming the pairs with `sliding`, e.g.

```
val x = List("a", "b", "c")
(x.last :: x).sliding(2,1).toList // gives List(List(c, a), List(a, b), List(b, c))
```

(Strictly, `last` is not a very efficient method on `scala.List`, but it works)

Then you would have

```
pairs.count { case Seq(pi, pj) => checkCondition } % 2 == 1
```

Where the `case Seq(pi, pj)` extracts for you again the adjacent points, and `% 2 == 1` asks if you counted an odd number of times.

---

An alternative to the sliding would be to use the `foldLeft` method. This might be a bit more performative, as no nested collections are created, but more of a smartass solution. The trick is to pass around the previous point *and* the current result (`c` in your original code):

```
poly.foldLeft(poly.last -> false) { case ((pj, c), pi) => pi -> (c ^ checkCondition)}
```

This uses again pattern matching (`case ...`) for an elegant unpacking of the folded arguments.

Comment: I'm not sure I am following how you are checking against the actual point coordinates here?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sealed case class Loc(lat: Double, long: Double)

def isPointInPolygon(poly: List[Loc], x: Loc): Boolean = {
  (poly.last :: poly).sliding(2).foldLeft(false) { case (c, List(i, j)) =>
    val cond = {
      (
        (i.lat <= x.lat && x.lat < j.lat) ||
        (j.lat <= x.lat && x.lat < i.lat)
      ) &&
      (x.long < (j.long - i.long) * (x.lat - i.lat) / (j.lat - i.lat) + i.long)
    }

    if (cond) !c else c
  }
}
```